# Java connecting to Oracle Grid - DB connection string

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

**This is DB connection string to Oracle**

```
ABCSERVICE =
 (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername1-vip.test.ampf.com)(PORT = 1521))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername2-vip.test.ampf.com)(PORT = 1521))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername3-vip.test.ampf.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = ABCSERVICE)
)
)
```

I used one of the server and the conenction is working. I need help in having the connection string done for the above Oracle grid
one so that if there is fail over the next server is picked up

**Connection string for one server**

jdbc:oracle:thin:@//servername1-vip.test.ampf.com/ABCSERVICE

**Program for Single Server**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBConnection {

public static void executeQuery(final Connection connection) throws SQLException
  {
      try{

            // test the conenction here and it works

            }

        }catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
  }



public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception{

Connection connection = null;
try {
    // Load the JDBC driver
    String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    Class.forName(driverName);

    // Create a connection to the database
    String serverName = "servername1-vip.test.ampf.com";
    String portNumber = "1521";
    String serviceName = "ABCSERVICE";

    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + "/" + serviceName;
    System.out.println(url);
    String username = "userName";
    String password = "passWord";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

    executeQuery(connection);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Could not connect to the database
    System.out.println(e);
}

}
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the JDBC url, just replace everything after the '@' with the string starting from "(DESCRIPTION". I.e:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername1-vip.test.ampf.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername2-vip.test.ampf.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername3-vip.test.ampf.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
    (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = ABCSERVICE)
    )
)
```

You can also set up a [tnsnames file](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) and [refer to that](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) instead, but I'm only vaguely familiar with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to get the oracle connection string. hostPortMap is map of server name and port. So, using the value from your example

```
Map<String, String> hostPortMap  = new HashMap();
hostPortMap.put("servername1-vip.test.ampf.com", "1521");
hostPortMap.put("servername2-vip.test.ampf.com", "1521");
hostPortMap.put("servername3-vip.test.ampf.com", "1521");


    public static String getOracleConnectionString(Map<String, String> hostPortMap, String serviceName){

        String connectionURLTemplate =  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description ={0}(connect_data=(service_name={1})))";
        String addressTemplate = "(address = (protocol = tcp)(host = {0})(port = {1}))";


        StringBuilder addresses = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hostPortMap.entrySet()){
             addresses.append(MessageFormat.format(addressTemplate, new Object[]{entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()})) ;
        }
        String connectionURL = MessageFormat.format(connectionURLTemplate, new Object[]{addresses, serviceName});
        System.out.println(connectionURL);
        return connectionURL;
    }
```